# How do I add and subtract numbers in an arraylist (in my specific condition)?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, switch-statement

In my bank application, users are able to create multiple accounts. Now I am adding an extra feature so that it can perform transaction within different accounts and also within the same account. At this moment, in summury, I have no idea how to make this happen.

***Specially: considering the block of code I have given below, once the `withdraw_accNum` is found in the array list, `withdraw_amount` must be subtracted from the current balance of `withdraw_accNum`. And after that that value must be added to the current balance of `deposit_accNum`. And of course the array should be updated according to the transaction I made so that it can get diplayed with the recent status.*
 `case 2:` should also follow this basic rules.**

This is my complete code for this application:

BankApp_Assignment:'

```
    package bankapp_assignment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApp_Assignment {

    static int numOfAcc = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR BANK!\n\n");

        List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option1;
        int option2;
        double withdraw_accNum;
        double deposit_accNum;

        double withdraw_amount;
        double dep_amount;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose your option:\n"
                    + "1. Create new account\n"//done
                    + "2. Deposit/withdraw\n"//working with this...
                    + "3. View One account\n"//not used yet
                    + "4. Deleting an account\n"//not used yet
                    + "5. View all the accounts\n"//done
                    + "6. Quit\n");//done
            System.out.println("*************\n"
                    + "************");

            option1 = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            //switch-case starts
            switch (option1) {
                case 1:
                    //create account
                    BankAccount bankAcc = new BankAccount();
                    System.out.println("Enter Full Name:");
                    bankAcc.setName(sc.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("Choose an Account Number:");
                    bankAcc.setAccNum(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Choose the initial amount:");
                    bankAcc.setInitiateAmount(sc.nextDouble());
                    //adding those into the arrayList
                    bankAccounts.add(bankAcc);
                    System.out.println("-------------\n"
                            + "-------------");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //First displaying the current accouns info
                    System.out.println("Name \tAccount No \tInitial Amount");
                    for (BankAccount bankAccount : bankAccounts) {

                        System.out.println(bankAccount);

                    }

                    System.out.println("\t\t.........\n"
                            + "\t\t.........");

                    System.out.println("To transfer money within the bank accounts enter 1\n"
                            + "To deposit/withdraw money in the same account enter 2");
                    option2 = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();

                    //inner switch-case starts
                    switch (option2) {
                        case 1:

                            System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to withdraw from:");

                            withdraw_accNum = sc.nextDouble();

                            System.out.println("Enter the amount you want to withdraw:");

                            withdraw_amount = sc.nextDouble();

                            System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to deposit to:");

                            deposit_accNum = sc.nextDouble();//the deposit amount is alwyas the same as withdraw_amount

                            break;
                        case 2://deposit/withdraw money in the same accounts
                            System.out.println("Enter the account number you want to deposit or withdraw from:");
                            //read the accNum
                            System.out.println("Enter the amount (To withdraw enter a negative value)");
                            //read the amount
                            break;
                    }

                    //inner switch-case ends
                    System.out.println("\n\n");
                    break;

                case 3:
                //View One account
                case 4:
                //Deleting an account

                case 5:
                    //View all the accounts/printing them out
                    System.out.println("Name\tAccount No\tInitial Amount");
                    for (BankAccount bankAccount : bankAccounts) {

                        System.out.println(bankAccount);

                    }

                    System.out.println("\n\n");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    //Quit
                    return;
            }

            //switch-case ends
        }

    }

}
```

BankAccount:

```
package bankapp_assignment;

public class BankAccount {

    private String name;
    private int accNum;
    private double initiateAmount;

    //constructor
    public BankAccount() {

        this.name = null;
        this.accNum = 0;
        this.initiateAmount = 0;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public void setAccNum(int accNum) {

        this.accNum = accNum;
    }

    public void setInitiateAmount(double initiateAmount) {
        this.initiateAmount = initiateAmount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "\t\t" + accNum + "\t\t" + initiateAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: It will take too much time to read through all your codes to understand what you want. To keep it simple, are you asking how to manipulate the objects within an ArrayList?

Comment: yeas. do u think I should re-ask this question? actually its not that big and vague post as you thought. the only thing you need to read is what is written in bold Italic font.

Comment: Look at my solution below. It is as easy as one line of code actually. Just get the object reference and deduct money from it. `account.deductAmount(amt);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping an `ArrayList` of `BankAccount`, keep a `HashMap` with key as account number and value as BankAccount object.

`Map<int, BankAccount> bankAccounts = new HashMap<int, BankAccount>();`

when you add an account, simply do-

`bankAccounts.put(accNum, bankAccount);`

and when you want to subtract withdraw amount-

`BankAccount bankAccount = bankAccounts.get(accNum);`

and then you can manipulate `amount` by using its `setters` and `getters`.

Answer (score 0):

> Specially: considering the block of code I have given below, once the withdraw_accNum is found in the array list, withdraw_amount must be subtracted from the current balance of withdraw_accNum. And after that that value must be added to the current balance of deposit_accNum. And of course the array should be updated according to the transaction I made so that it can get diplayed with the recent status. case 2: should also follow this basic rules.

To check whether entered Bank Account number is correct while withdrawing is simple enough. I guess you have no problem with that. You can just loop through all arraylist elements and check whether each bank account's accNum match with given account number.

To manipulate the arraylist elements is very simple.

1. Get the reference of the bank account object you are interested to manipulate.

   ```
   BankAccount b, acc = null;
   for(int x=0; x<bankAccounts.size(); x++){
       b = bankAccounts.get(x);
       if(givenAcc == b.getAccNum())
           acc = b;;
   }
   ```
2. If account exist, deduct money from that account

   ```
   //Assume user already input amount to withdraw

   if(acc != null) //if account exist
       b.deductAmount(amt);
   else
       System.out.println("Account does not exist");
   ```

That's all. It is very simple. Just a one line thing.

I advise you to modularize your main into sub-methods. You also seem to have many mutator and accssor methods missing in your BankAccount Class.

It is advisible to have a `deductAmount(double amt)` method to deduct amount of money.

Comment: user3437460,Thank you, your explanation in words make a lots of sense to me, but I am lost while looking your solution in coding. First of all, I already have a BankAccount object created, do I need another one like you named it "b"? In your for loop where do you get the getAccNum() from? YOu mean I have to create this method to call here? Secondly, deductAmount(amt) also confused me in the similar way! Hope to hear you.

Comment: @Riyana Like I said in my solution, there are many methods you have to create in your BankAccount class and within the runner class (the class where your main resides). It is better for you to create those methods like `deductAmount()`. If you do not want to do that, you can use back your setInitialAmount() for deduction. `But this seems bad to me`. `b` is just a variable. It can be anything! Of course you have a to declare something to hold the reference like `b`. But it can be any name, most importantly, it is a variable of data type `BankAccount`.